# Can I remove the gwibber packages without removing ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: gwibber

Gwibber as I can remove without removing important parts of ubuntu, it asks me to remove Gwibber also remove ubuntu desktop

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which utility are you using to remove Gwibber? Is it, the Ubuntu software Centre? Is it, Synaptic Package Manager? Is it, the terminal? Synaptic will warn you of the packages that it wants to remove. You can then search for those you do not want removed and with a right click select Unmark. Do this before you click Apply.

Comment: I use ubuntu 11.10, the application software I use is ubuntu center to delete, test them as you say thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove gwibber you just have to use this code on the terminal (ctrl + alt + t)

```
sudo apt-get purge gwibber.*
```

Comment: and using the purge command did not remove ubuntu-desktop software you want to remove ubuntu center??

Comment: I also want to remove Gwibber, but when doing the command above, it asks to remove 8 packages, "ubuntu-desktop" being one of them. Ive accidentally removed that before only to screw up my system.

Comment: Ho, I didn't saw that... Well, I guess you can't remove Gwibber because it is part of unity itself... That is really strange, if I didn't use social networks I would want to remove it too.

Comment: I always uninstall gwibber on our work machines. You should be able to safely remove it. "ubuntu-desktop" is a meta-package that installs all of the packages required for an Ubuntu GUI, but removing it will not uninstall all of those packages.